# C# Code Analyzing tools for Linux with Mono framework that work with Command Line

Tags: linux, c#, command-line, code-analysis, mono

Is there any tool that can dynamic or static analyison C# code and can be executed via Commandline/Terminal on a Linux machine that features the Mono (Open Source .NET) Framework?

SonarQube (with its SonarScanner) was quite promising because actaully they run both on Linux but alas C# code cannot be analysed anymore with SonarScanner because now it requires MS Build 14 and that is not included in Mono.

Comment: Semantic Design's (my company's) "dynamic analysis" test coverage tool for C# should work fine with Mono under Linux.  Is this along the lines that interests you?